Prove that fourier serie $f(x)$ is $\pi^2 / 6 = 1 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + \ldots$
i have some difficults to prove that the fourier series of
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & -\pi < x \leq 0, \\
x^2, & 0 < x \leq \pi.
\end{cases}
$$
can be aproximated to
$$ \frac{\pi^2}{6} = 1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \ldots$$
My attempt:
I computed the fourier series of $f$ and i get:
$$f(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} + \sum_k^\infty \left(\frac{2(-1)^k}{k^2}\cos(kx) + \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\frac{-\pi^2k^2(-1)^k + 2(-1)^k-2}{k^3}\right]\sin(kx)\right)$$
If $x = 0$ then
$0 = f(0) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} + \displaystyle\sum_k^{\infty} \frac{2(-1)^k}{k^2}$
that implies
$\frac{\pi^2}{6} = -\displaystyle\sum_k^{\infty} \frac{2(-1)^k}{k^2}$
Here i'm stuck, can someone help me?


$\displaystyle \sum_{k}^{\infty}$? What's the range of it? 2) When the sum term is so long, putting parentheses on it can make it easy to read. 3) I computed the Fourier series - where did it come from? Did you put it in Wolfram Alpha or somewhere else? Please check the trustability of the Fourier series.


I computed the Serie of Fourier on Wolfram/Symbolab!.. thx

Your title and question are confusing: you want to compute the value of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ by computing the Fourier series of $f$ and not that the Fourier series of $f$ is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, which is a number.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-ways-to-prove-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2-frac-pi26-the-b/8378#8378

\begin{align}
& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}. \tag{A}\label{A}\\
& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2k)^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{24}. \tag{B}\label{B}\\
& \text{Take } (\ref{A})-2(\ref{B}): \\
& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{(2k-1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(2k)^2}\right) - 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2k)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{(2k-1)^2} - \dfrac{1}{(2k)^2}\right) \\ & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} - \dfrac{\pi^2}{12} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}. \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} + 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k^2} = 0. \blacksquare
\end{align}
